# How do I build a static library for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gcc, compiler-construction

I think that I've looked everywhere for an answer to my problem but without any luck.

I'm trying to create a simple static lib to run on the iPhone device but I keep ending up with XCode saying that "file is not of required architecture" and I've tried every build flag that I found without any luck.

I've got it to work on the emulator building it like this:

$gcc-4.2 -c StaticHelloWorld.c -o StaticHelloWorld.o 
$ar rcs libstatichelloworld.a StaticHelloWorld.o

But how do I build it for device??

Regards,
drisse

Answer (score 2):

Within Xcode, there is a New Project template called Cocoa Touch Static Library.  This template provides most of the setup you need for creating a static library.  You then just need to include your various source files, as well as your shared header file.

For an example of iPhone static libraries, see the [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) and [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) projects.  Both employ static libraries for the iPhone.  We have some [instructions on how to include the library within an application](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) in the main Core Plot wiki.

Comment: I had to cross compile the lib for apple-darwin in order to get this to work: 
$ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1 -c StaticHelloWorld.c -o StaticHelloWorldArm.o
$ ar rcs libstatichelloworld.a StaticHelloWorldArm.o