# How to build my own library in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I created some libraries that I want to give others, but I don't want to share the source code to them (I don't want to give the .h, .m). How can I pack my code to others in XCode? thz.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a static library for iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518981/how-do-i-build-a-static-library-for-iphone)

Comment: Tattat, do you want these for iPhone or OSX development? Do you want static libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Xcodes *Cocoa Framework* template, you don't have to do much - the basic framework already gets generated for you in `build/Mode/`.

The [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1) should get you going and includes sections on [exports](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/ExportingInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002260-97049) and [installation](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/InstallingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002261-BBCCFBJA).

*Note:* Don't forget to set a reasonable version for the Base SDK.